# how to deal with JSON response

Tags: javascript, python, json, websocket

I'm using Python websockets to return JSON objects (I think) however I'm not sure how to deal with the response. I have an example using JavaScript which uses parseJSON, a snippet is bellow:

```
socket = io.connect("__socket address__");
socket.on("connect", function() {socket.emit("subscribe_areas", areas)});
var d = jQuery.parseJSON(c);
console.log(d);
d.type == "INTERPOSE";
```

which returns data I can access eg d.type == "INTERPOSE";:

```
Object {area: "BE", type: "MOVE", to: "0109", from: "0107", value: "2L65"}
Object {area: "BE", type: "MOVE", to: "0113", from: "0109", value: "2L65"}
```

where as my Python I recieve:

```
(u'{"area":"EH","type":"INTERPOSE","to":"B243","value":""}',)
(u'{"area":"EH","type":"INTERPOSE","to":"0337","value":""}',)
(u'{"area":"EH","type":"INTERPOSE","to":"0085","value":""}',)
```

Why does the python return JSON wrapped in brackets and commars? My Python is bellow:

```
from socketIO_client import SocketIO
import logging
import json
def on_connect():
    print('CONNECTED')
    areas = ['EH']
    socketIO.emit('subscribe_areas', areas)
def on_message(*answer):
    print(answer)
socketIO = SocketIO('_address_', _port_)
socketIO.on('connect', on_connect)
socketIO.on('message', on_message)
socketIO.wait()
```

I've tried decoding using json.load, json.loads, json.decode but recieve all sorts of errors. What am I missing and why is the return wrapped in brackets and such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You told Python to expect 0 or more arguments:

```
def on_message(*answer):
    print(answer)
```

Python then gives you a tuple of all arguments passed in; your print statements show you got one argument, so you got a tuple with just one element in it. That one element is a JSON string that you'd decode with `json.loads()`.

Take the first element and decode that:

```
def on_message(*answer):
    print(json.loads(answer[0]))
```

or don't use `*` and require that one argument is passed in, always and load from that one argument

```
def on_message(answer):
    print(json.loads(answer))
```